# International Time Notation

Tags: time

I know some ways for time notation.

10 am
10:30 am
10.30 am
10<sup>30</sup> am (superscript)

I try to understand, is it correct to use superscript in time notation on international website?

Comment: I have rarely seen this, so I suggest you stay away from it. Stick with the standard 10:30 am at least for English-language web sites.

Comment: I have never, ever seen the superscript version before. I suppose I could get used to it but at first sight I think it would look like a mistake - at least to British people.

Comment: the first three are fine. On most booking websites, the 24 hour format is more common, where you don't have to use AM and PM.

Comment: This isn't a question about the English language.

Answer (score 1):

Superscript is never correct for minutes. [Source & exanples](http://www.timeandunits.com/time-and-date-format.html)  (Sometimes it is used for seconds though).

Different time and date formats are normally converted to a person's preferred settings if you use a time or date format tool built into whatever tool or programming language the website is in. It picks up the **locale** on the computer/phont being used, eg English (US) or English (Au). Many short lines of code will do this formatting for a regular website.

For international websites using 24hr notation would make time conversions easier if time is a significant part of the website - especially if you want to display the time zone as well, eg.

**10:30 EST**  or  **10:30 GMT+8** (8 hrs ahead of GMT)

Normally computer stick to converting times to and from UTC (universal time),  which the computer then converts to something rather more friendly to look at.

Usually dates are the problematic part rather than times, since either MM DD YYYY or DD MM YYYY may be used.